# I can't get the values of textboxes

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I want to save the data from the textboxes into variables so I can send them to anotherpage using POST, I have three input tags inside a modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="salaryModal" >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group ">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="hourly rate" name="hourly_rate"/<br>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="overtime rate" name="overtime_rate"/<br>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="vacation rate" name="vacation rate"/<br>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($auth)) {
            $username = $row["username"]; ?>

              <input class="btn btn-success center-block" id="calculate_salary_button" onclick="assignsalary('<?php echo $username; ?>')" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/></a>
<?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } } ?>
          <!--span style="color:blue" id="span_result"></span-->


          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

the button calls assign salary on the username passed(which  works just fine)

```
function assignsalary(username) {
      var uname = username;
      var hour_rate = $("#hourly_rate").val();
      var overtime_rate = $("#overtime_rate").val();
      var vacation_rate = $("#vacation_rate").val();
      $('#test_box').html("");  
      $('#test_box').html(hour_rate);  
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('hourly_rate',hour_rate);
      data.append('username',uname);
      data.append('overtime_rate',overtime_rate);
      data.append('vacation_rate',vacation_rate);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'set_salary.php', true);
      xhr.onload = function () {
        $('#test_box').html("");  
        $('#test_box').html(this.responseText);
        };
      xhr.send(data);
    }
```

username is sent sucessfully, it's the other variablles that are not sent properly:

Here's what is returned from the set_salary:

> [age: username: adel hourly_rate: undefined overtime_rate: undefined vacation_rate: undefined

and here's the set_salary code:

```
<?php session_start();
$overtime_rate = $_POST['overtime_rate'];
$vacation_rate = $_POST['vacation_rate'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$hourly_rate = $_POST['hourly_rate'];
echo "username: {$username}\n";
echo "hourly_rate: {$hourly_rate}\n";
echo "overtime_rate: {$overtime_rate}\n";
echo "vacation_rate: {$vacation_rate}\n";
?>
```

Comment: you didn't assign any ID's - assign them and check your console again.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid in the first code. Close your `input` tags properly before `<br />`

Comment: they were indeed, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `Id` in `<input>` And, didn't closed `<input>` tag

**UPDATD CODE**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="salaryModal" >
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group ">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="hourly rate" id="hourly_rate" name="hourly_rate"/><br>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="overtime rate" id="overtime_rate" name="overtime_rate"/><br>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="vacation rate" id="vacation_rate" name="vacation rate"/><br>
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($auth)) {
      $username = $row["username"]; ?>

        <input class="btn btn-success center-block" id="calculate_salary_button" onclick="assignsalary('<?php echo $username; ?>')" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/></a>
<?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } } ?>
    <!--span style="color:blue" id="span_result"></span-->


    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

function assignsalary(username) {
      var uname = username;
      var hour_rate = $("#hourly_rate").val();
      var overtime_rate = $("#overtime_rate").val();
      var vacation_rate = $("#vacation_rate").val();
      $('#test_box').html("");  
      $('#test_box').html(hour_rate);  
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('hourly_rate',hour_rate);
      data.append('username',uname);
      data.append('overtime_rate',overtime_rate);
      data.append('vacation_rate',vacation_rate);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'set_salary.php', true);
      xhr.onload = function () {
        $('#test_box').html("");  
        $('#test_box').html(this.responseText);
        };
      xhr.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help @AdelAhmed

Answer (score 1):

Since you are capturing the values with id, give id to your textbox

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="hourly rate" name="hourly_rate" id="hourly_rate"/><br>
                                                                                     ^                ^
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="overtime rate" name="overtime_rate" id="overtime_rate"/><br>
                                                                                         ^                ^
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="vacation rate" name="vacation rate" id="overtime_rate"/><br>
                                                                                         ^                ^
```

Then you can capture values using `id`